# MockMvc reach the @Controller class although servlet mapping filtering

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring and this is my first question in Stack Overflow, my english also is basic...

I'm currently following the http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/3/ and I don't understand why the MvcMock can perform a `get("/bbb")` and reach my controller (mapped to `@RequestMapping("/bbb")`) even the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` restrict the `DispatcherSevlet` mappings to `new String[] { "/aaa" };`?

Here is the code involved...

**The Spring WebAppInitializer**

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { PersistenceConfig.class, CoreConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/aaa" };
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter };
}
}
```

**The Spring controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bbb")
public class SiteController {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SiteController.class);

@Autowired
private MenuService menuService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getCurrentMenu() {
    ...
}
```

**And the JUnit test that passes**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { PersistenceConfig.class, CoreConfig.class, WebConfig.class })
public class WebDomainIntegrationTest {

private static final String STANDARD = "Yummy Noodles";
private static final String CHEF_SPECIAL = "Special Yummy Noodles";
private static final String LOW_CAL = "Low cal Yummy Noodles";

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void thatTextReturned() throws Exception {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/bbb")).andDo(print()).andExpect(content().string(containsString(STANDARD)))
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString(CHEF_SPECIAL))).andExpect(content().string(containsString(LOW_CAL)));

}

}
```

Thank's a lot for your help!

Laurent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that your `MockMvc` configuration is not using your `WebAppInitializer`. [This currently isn't supported by the Spring MVC test suite.](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10199?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) Notice how you haven't registered anywhere. All you've done is to setup your context configuration with

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { PersistenceConfig.class, CoreConfig.class, WebConfig.class })
```

With that and

```
@WebAppConfiguration
```

`MockMvc` will register a `DispatcherServlet` with the `@Controller` classes in your context (and other things it looks for). It will then run the tests with that configuration. There is no `/aaa` in that configuration. All paths are absolute, as they are declared in your `@Controller` classes.

Comment: So. I'm trying to write spring security mockmvc tests and my filter chains configured to this servlet mapping "/aaa". How could I configure mockMvc to catch servlet configuration?